# Cognito method to see if a user exists with username

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-cognito

Is there a method in Cognito that tells you if a user exists with a specific username before calling signUp()?

Or is there a method that can look up a user? fetchUserAttributes will send the current user's attributes but not a specific username's

I think something like this would be useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html
but i'm not sure how to implement the ListUsers() method in Flutter

Comment: I don't know anything about flutter, but you can get info on a user by username using [`AdminGetUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html). It's available in various SDKs, like [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp/client/admin_get_user.html). Will that work for you?

Comment: @NickK9 Am aware of AdminGetUser but I am not sure what correct syntax to use in flutter